# Pre Operation Concurrent Plugins Getting MAXIMUM Existing Field Value For An Entity Records

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to set a field (Record Number) on an entity in Pre-Operation plugin that triggers on create  with an incremental number based on previous one. For example if the MAX Previous Record Number is 4 I will set the one being created to 5. I am using LINQ to get the MAX exiting number from entity records and then incremented by 1.
My concern is that, what if 2 or more plugins execute at the same time and does the same thing. Does CRM has a sequential mechanism to force the plugins to run in sequential order and if NOT how can I avoid 2 plugins getting the same previous maximum record number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way CRM supports concurrence is:
1. The plug-in must be in the pre or post operation.
2. You need to update one field on the entity you need. (Whatever value you want).
3. You add your logic here.

The third step will grant you one plug-in execute that logic and the others will wait for it until it ends.

Edit:
This is what you need:

```
Entity context = (Entity)executionContext.InputParameters["Target"];
Entity entity = new Entity { LogicalName = "salesorder", Id = context.Id };
entity["new_dummyfield"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
service.Update(entity); // Lock

entity = service.Retrieve("salesorder", context.Id, new ColumnSet("new_autonumber"));
if (!entity.Contains("new_autonumber"))
{
    return;
}
int autonumber = (int)entity["new_autonumber"] + 1;
entity["new_autonumber"] = autonumber;
service.Update(entity);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have changed my plugin so it will be doing the following; 1- Read Field value. 2- Update this field by incrementing it by 1. Does this guarantee pessimistic concurrency for multiple instances of this plugin?

Comment: You need to retrieve the entity, update de dummy field, retrieve again the entity and read the field you need to update, increment that field. This supports the concurrency.

Comment: Thanks again. When you say dummy field are you referring to the field that I need to update? I have one field that I retrieve the value from and then increment it by 1.

Comment: A dummy field is a value you update to gain the control of the transaction, usually is a string and you update there random guids. Because you only do this for the transaction you should not involve bussiness fields for this purpose.

Comment: So I create a new field on the entity and update it with a new generated  GUID then read the other field and then incremented by 1. Correct?

Comment: I made and edit with a code sample, hope this works because I dont have my IDE right now, if you have any questions, just ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple plugins can indeed run concurrently therefore you cannot guarantee uniqueness of any values calculated in this way.  Many solutions use an external database for auto number but keep in mind you won't be able to access this database from a Sandbox plugin.

There is a way in which you can achieve isolation using a custom entity removing the need for the external database discussed [here](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2012/01/implementing-robust-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-auto-numbering-using-transactions/).  However, as you'll read, it's not an out of the box feature.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I am a bit confused about what the article you referred to says. Should I create a new entity "Sequential" and from my plugin I generate a new GUID and update the "dummy field" on the sequential entity and at the same time I read and update the sequential number field?